# Map identity functor over record

Tags: haskell, functor, template-haskell

I have a record type like this one:

```
data VehicleState f = VehicleState
                      {
                        orientation :: f (Quaternion Double),
                        orientationRate :: f (Quaternion Double),
                        acceleration :: f (V3 (Acceleration Double)),
                        velocity :: f (V3 (Velocity Double)),
                        location :: f (Coordinate),
                        elapsedTime :: f (Time Double)
                      }
                    deriving (Show)
```

This is cool, because I can have a `VehicleState Signal` where I have all sorts of metadata, I can have a `VehicleState (Wire s e m ())` where I have the `netwire` semantics of each signal, or I can have a `VehicleState Identity` where I have actual values observed at a certain time.

Is there a good way to map back and forth between `VehicleState Identity` and `VehicleState'`, defined by mapping `runIdentity` over each field?

```
data VehicleState' = VehicleState'
                      {
                        orientation :: Quaternion Double,
                        orientationRate :: Quaternion Double,
                        acceleration :: V3 (Acceleration Double),
                        velocity :: V3 (Velocity Double),
                        location :: Coordinate,
                        elapsedTime :: Time Double
                      }
                    deriving (Show)
```

Obviously it's trivial to write one, but I actually have several types like this in my real application and I keep adding or removing fields, so it is tedious.

I am writing some Template Haskell that does it, just wondering if I am reinventing the wheel.

Comment: You might be able to do this with GHC Generics, but I don't know if it'd be any simpler than TH.  Since I have experience with TH, that'd be my choice as well.

Comment: What I would consider: don't use `VehicleState'` at all, and make a short alias for `Identity` and `runIdentity`.  I know, not great.

Comment: Or use [newtype](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/newtype) and its helpers.

Comment: `Identity` is a newtype, so `cast :: VehicleState Identity -> VehicleState'; cast = unsafeCoerce` is, in this case, actually safe. (obviously the same for the inverse)

Comment: I agree with @luqui's suggestion; I've used it and it works well.  Just derive lenses to access each field of `VehicleState`, and then you can access the `Identity`-wrapped variants by composing `wrapped` or `unwrapped` with the lens.

Comment: @JohnL, if you have time could you elaborate? I don't understand lenses yet.

Comment: @user2407038, Is it safe in this case? How do we know that the compiler decided to layout the two records in the same order? Is it guaranteed to happen in source order?

Comment: @DougMcClean If by 'guaranteed' you mean the compiler promises to do it that way, then no, I don't believe so. But it is certainly done that way. We know because the `cast` function does not cause the universe to explode.

Answer (score 4):

If you're not opposed to type families and don't need too much type inference, you can actually get away with using a single datatype:

```
import Data.Singletons.Prelude

data Record f = Record
  { x :: Apply f Int
  , y :: Apply f Bool
  , z :: Apply f String
  }

type Record' = Record IdSym0

test1 :: Record (TyCon1 Maybe)
test1 = Record (Just 3) Nothing (Just "foo")

test2 :: Record'
test2 = Record 2 False "bar"
```

The `Apply` type family is defined in the [singletons](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/singletons) package. It can be applied to
various type functions also defined in that package (and of course, you can define your
own). The `IdSym0` has the property that `Apply IdSym0 x` reduces to plain `x`. And
`TyCon1` has the property that `Apply (TyCon1 f) x` reduces to `f x`.

As demonstrated by
`test1` and `test2`, this allows both versions of your datatype. However, you need
type annotations for most records now.